# AirDrop disable detect and set in macOS

Tags: macos, nsuserdefaults, airdrop, cfpreferences

I'd like to get the current AirDrop status in my macOS machines.

I used to check it by reading the value of `DisableAirDrop` in domain `com.apple.NetworkBrowser` but this seems to be deprecated in latest OS versions (High Sierra and above) and now it doesn't really disable airDrop.

Instead, I check for the `DiscoverableMode` value in domain `com.apple.sharingd` is set to `Off` in the following manner :

`defaults read com.apple.sharingd DiscoverableMode | grep 'Off'`

I'd like to know whether this field (DiscoverableMode) is applicable only for airDrop only ?

In addition, is there any way i can check this for all active users and not just for current user ?

thanks